# Why is my component not updated after using map?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I used a map in the data structure, but the components will not update when my data is updated. Why is this?

I use `console.log` to output 5 pieces of data, but there are only 3 pieces of data on the page, which will not be updated!!!

[image]

#### Component

```
import React, {ChangeEventHandler, Component} from "react";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {RootState} from "typesafe-actions";
import {getMessage} from "./store/selectors";
import {submitComment} from './store/actions'

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    submit: submitComment
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => {
    return {
        article: getMessage(state.article, 1)
    }
}

type Props = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps> & typeof mapDispatchToProps;

type State = {
    value: string
}

class Todo extends Component<Props, State> {
    readonly state = {value: ''}


    public render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.props.article?.title}</h1>

                {this.props.article?.comments.map((comment) => <li key={comment.title}>{comment.title}</li>)}

                <input type="text" onChange={this.onChange}/>

                <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>submit</button>
            </div>
        )
    }

    private handleSubmit = () => {
        this.props.submit(this.state.value);
    }

    private onChange: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (e) => {
        this.setState({value: e.currentTarget.value});
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Todo);
```

#### reducer.ts

```
import {createReducer, PayloadAction} from "typesafe-actions";
import * as actions from './actions';

interface Comment {
    title: string
}

interface Article {
    title: string
    comments: Comment[]
}

interface App {
    articles: Map<number, Article>
}

const initState: App = {
    articles: new Map<number, Article>([
        [1, {title: 'article', comments: [{title: 'comment-1'}, {title: 'comment-2'}]}]
    ])
}

export const articleReducer = createReducer<App>(initState)
    .handleAction(actions.submitComment, (state: App, action: PayloadAction<string, string>) => {
        const article = state.articles.get(1)
        article?.comments.push({title: action.payload})

        console.log(article?.comments);

        return {
            articles: state.articles
        }
    });


export default articleReducer;

export type ArticleState = ReturnType<typeof articleReducer>;
```

#### actions.ts

```
import {createAction} from "typesafe-actions";

export const submitComment = createAction("SUBMIT_COMMENT", (title: string) => (title))();
```

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet

Comment: You should start with removing [non serializable](https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#can-i-put-functions-promises-or-other-non-serializable-items-in-my-store-state) values such as [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) from redux state (make it an array). And then not [mutate that array](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) when you update it.

Comment: Map can quickly query the required data, if you use an array, the query will become very troublesome! ; @HMR

Comment: @jack  Programmers ignoring advice from the writers of the libraries they use is even more troublesome than finding an item in an array.

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestion. I will use `immutable` to try to rewrite the data structure!!! @HMR

Comment: redux advices immer, but this is not even about mutating but storing non serializable data in state. This will break many of the extensions made for redux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your articleReduce is modifying an existing state value `comments` instead of creating a copy in an immutable way:

```js
export const articleReducer = createReducer<App>(initState)
    .handleAction(actions.submitComment, (state: App, action: PayloadAction<string, string>) => {
        return {
            articles: state.articles.map((article, idx) => idx !== 1 ? article : { ...article, comments: [...article.comments, action.payload] })
        }
    });
```

If you want to use mutable logic (like `.push`) in reducers, please see [redux toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/)  which is the official recommendation to write redux (and works very well with TypeScript) anyways.

Answer (score -2):

you use 'readonly' modifier in

readonly state = {value: ''}

it meaning that 'state' cannot be reassigned

Comment: readonly is a TypeScript modifier without any consequences for runtime JavaScript.
Also, the local component state does not seem to play any role in the question.

Comment: Almost equal to:
```tsx
constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: ''}
    }
```